# PowerPoint Add-on's weird behavior

Tags: vba, vsto, powerpoint

I'm developing a `PowerPoint2007` Add-on using `VSTO(Visual Studio Tools for Office)`
I'm trying to add a `wavfile` to slide and modify animation setting of the wave file.
The problem is occurred when I modify `AnimationSettings.PlaySettings's` member attributes of the wave file shape then some of animation effect in the slide deleted.
This behavior is very weird.
I don't understand why some of animation effect has been deleted after I modify the PlaySettings's member attributes.

code :

```
Shape s = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.Slides[slideIndex].Shapes.AddMediaObject(wavFilePath, 0f, 0f);
s.Left = DEFAULT_LEFT_POS;

// If the below code run, some of animation effect are deleted.
s.AnimationSettings.Animate = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
s.AnimationSettings.AdvanceMode = PpAdvanceMode.ppAdvanceOnTime;
s.AnimationSettings.AnimationOrder = 0;
s.AnimationSettings.PlaySettings.PauseAnimation = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
s.AnimationSettings.PlaySettings.PlayOnEntry = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my experiences using `AnimationSettings` delete all 'exit effects' of other shapes. What you could possibly try is to explore the following PowerPoint objects/references:

```
`(slide).TimeLine.MainSequence`
```

which allows to change the animation order (you could add sound shape and than move it up before any exit effect start).

Check also if `(Shape).SoundEffect` object is not a good substitution for your needs.
I also change tag of your question into powerpoint-vba as it has a reference to that area too.